# Плагин image2 (Enhanced Image) убирает нужный функционал из ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Проблема в том, что при подключении плагина image2 (Enhanced Image) он убирает нужный мне функционал программы и функций диалогового окна становится заметно меньше. Сам плагин мне нужен, так что комментарии и ответы с "Удали этот плагин" не принимаются.

**Функционал с image2 (Enhanced Image)**

[image: Функционал с image2 (Enhanced Image)]

**Функционал БЕЗ image2 (Enhanced Image)**

[image: Функционал БЕЗ image2 (Enhanced Image)]

Comment: У этого плагина такой функционал. Чтобы что то добавить, нужно дописывать плагин.